Integration giving two different outputs despite equivalent inputs?
Problem:
I have the following integral:
FullSimplify[
 Integrate[(Q1/(2 Exp[t v] + N1) + Q2/(Q3 - Q4 (2 Exp[t v] + N1))), {t, 
   0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {Q1 > 0, Q2 > 0, Q3 > 0, Q4 > 0, v > 0, N1 > 0}]]

I have found that Mathematica gives a different answer to that integral if it is calculated as a sum of two integrals:
FullSimplify[Integrate[Q1/(2 Exp[t v] + N1), {t, 0, Infinity},Assumptions -> {Q1 > 0, Q2 > 0, Q3 > 0, Q4 > 0, v > 0, N1 > 0}] + Integrate[Q2/(Q3 - Q4 (2 Exp[t v] + N1)),{t, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {Q1 > 0, Q2 > 0, Q3 > 0, Q4 > 0, v > 0, N1 > 0}]].

Question:
Can anyone help me understand a.) why the two ways of calculating the same integral are not giving the same answer; and b.) how I can make them match? Ultimately, I am hoping to derive Mathematica's solution to the first integral by hand, and I want my first step to be splitting the integrand into the sum in the second code.
Any help would be greatly appreciated; thank you so much!!


I have found that Mathematica gives a different answer to that
integral if it is calculated as a sum of two integrals:

How did you decide the answers are different?
I do not see any difference. V 14.1. May be you are using older version?
e1 = Q1/(2 Exp[t v] + N1)
e2 = Q2/(Q3 - Q4 (2 Exp[t v] + N1))
e = e1+e2
assume = {Q1 > 0, Q2 > 0, Q3 > 0, Q4 > 0, v > 0, N1 > 0}

Now (used GenerateConditions -> False to speed it up, else it was too slow for me)
eAnti = Integrate[e, {t, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> assume, GenerateConditions -> False]

e1Anti = Integrate[e1, {t, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> assume, GenerateConditions -> False]
    
e2Anti = Integrate[e2, {t, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> assume, GenerateConditions -> False]

Check
Simplify[eAnti - (e1Anti + e2Anti)]

(* 0 *)

